# How can i return the Nth digit of a list in python?

Tags: python, list, digits

```
X = [1,4,5,10,23,2,5,7,19]
```

I want to know the **digit Nth** of the list...

Example:

```
def func(n):
    print(nth digit of X)

def func(7):
print(7th digit of X)
Output = 3
```

Don't need to be a function...just the method to reach to **solution** of the problem: function **returns nth digit of a list**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation

Comment: Actually i used sliced but it gives me the n index of the list...what i want is the digit

Comment: Accessing elements of a list is covered in any decent python tutorial. A tutorial (many available online) or a tutor can help you better than Stack Overflow

Comment: Where did the 3 come from if `X = [1,4,5,10,23,2,5,7,19]` and you want the 7th "digit"?

Comment: @JustinEzequiel There are 9 numbers in the list and 12 digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = [1,4,5,10,23,2,5,7,19]

def func(x, n):
    return ''.join(map(str, x))[n-1]

print(func(x, 7))
```

Prints:

```
3
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Comment: Exactly what i need it! Ty! My Recaman sequence digit founder is complete!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the list to a str, and then the indexing would work

```
x_str = ''.join([str(i) for i in x])  # x_str = "145102325719" 
# x_str[idx] would return the digit
```